# How can I install gambas3 on ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, yumi

I tried to install [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) on ubuntu, I mean the multiboot-able creator, but it needs:

```
 yumi depends on gambas3-gb-runtime (>= 3.0.90); however:
  Package gambas3-gb-runtime is not installed.
 yumi depends on gambas3-gb-image (<< 3.99.0); however:
  Package gambas3-gb-runtime is not installed.
 yumi depends on gambas3-gb-image (>= 3.0.90); however:
  Package gambas3-gb-image is not installed.
 yumi depends on gambas3-gb-image (<< 3.99.0); however:
  Package gambas3-gb-image is not installed.
 yumi depends on gambas3-gb-gtk (>= 3.0.90); however:
  Package gambas3-gb-gtk is not installed.
 yumi depends on gambas3-gb-gtk (<< 3.99.0); however:
  Package gambas3-gb-gtk is not installed.
 yumi depends on gambas3-gb-form (>= 3.0.90); however:
  Package gambas3-gb-form is not installed.
 yumi depends on gambas3-gb-form (<< 3.99.0); however:
  Package gambas3-gb-form is not installed.
```

How can I install `gambas3` on ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- gambas3 is available from official repository only for Ubuntu 13.04 or later

  See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gambas3
- For edge releases of gambas3 or previous Ubuntu (<=12.10)

  1. Use this PPA https://launchpad.net/~nemh/+archive/gambas3

     ```
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/gambas3
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get install gambas3
     ```
  2. `gambas3` is a single package (from ppa), we need to create a meta/dummy packages which cover all gambas3 expected packages (`gambas3-gb-runtime`, `gambas3-gb-image`...)

     ```
     sudo apt-get install equivs

     equivs-control gambas3-gb-runtime
     equivs-build gambas3-gb-runtime
     sudo dpkg -i gambas3-gb-runtime-dummy_*.deb
     ```

     Same step for all `gambas3-gb-*` packages

     See [Creating Dummy Packages On Debian](http://eric.lubow.org/2010/system-administration/creating-dummy-packages-on-debian/)
  3. Install yumi

**Note**:

`equivs` is good way to resolve such dependency problems, when dependencies are installed from source or 3rd party packages.

Some changes may be needed to the created file by `equivs-build`, Like: Version to confirm the dependency condition.

Comment: see @Julio Sanchez answer below as the PPA above will not work with Trusty...

Answer (score 3):

The PPP nemh this no longer updated, now we must use this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gambas-team/gambas3  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gambas3
```

For more information:

http://cursogambas.blogspot.com.es/2012/08/instalacion-desde-repositorios-del.html